# Java - Set generic table with SQL results

Tags: java, sql, design-patterns

Below you can find the code that I'm using to retrieve a table from a generic SQL statement (the SQL code is inputed by the user in another part of the code).
Since I'll be storing more than one table in the future, and the retrieved table will have some format functions applied to it, I'm storing the values in a:

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<Object>>> tables = new HashMap<String, Map<String,List<Object>>>();
```

The first Map is a Table, the second is a Column and finally the list hold each line of data.

The column names/order in:

```
Map<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>> order = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>();
```

The Map is tha table, the TreeMap are the column number - column name

The code to create de generic table is:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
    String name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i); //Label vs name. Label is also what's defined by the user in: "as VENDA"
    answer.put(name, null);
    singleOrder.put(i, name);
}

while(rs.next()){
    Iterator answerIt = answer.entrySet().iterator();
    while (answerIt.hasNext()) { //Get Columns in index order to compare with body HashMap (unordered)
        Map.Entry columnNameValue = (Map.Entry)answerIt.next(); //key = columnName, value = List
        String columnName = (String) columnNameValue.getKey();


        List<Object> tmp = answer.get(columnName);
        if (tmp == null) {
            tmp = new ArrayList<Object>();
            answer.put(columnName, tmp);
        }

        Object item = rs.getObject(columnName);
        if(item instanceof Integer){
            item =  ((Integer) item).doubleValue();
        } else if (item instanceof Long){
            item =  ((Long) item).doubleValue();
        } else if (item instanceof BigDecimal){
            item =  ((BigDecimal) item).doubleValue();
        }
        tmp.add(item);

    }

}
```

Efficiency will be key for this part of my code. How can I improve the table creation? 
(I think this is a important question for Java coders, so a clear response can serve a pattern for future programmers that have the same difficulty that I'm having now)

---

Update 1:

Why I'm asking: I couldn't find any example of how to handle a flexible query in Java. I've created my own solution, but I fear it's some kind of monster compared to how to handle such a case properly in Java.

As example:

Lets say I'll name the result of a first query as "table1".
The query will be: Select STORE, SALES, GOAL, EXTRA from ... ;

The order variable will be like:

```
Map<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>> order = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>();

table1,
    1, "STORE"
    2, "SALES"
    3, "GOAL"
    4, "EXTRA"
```

The tables variable:

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<Object>>> tables = new HashMap<String, Map<String,List<Object>>>();

"table1", 
    "STORE", 
        "unit1"
        "unit2"
        "unit3"
        "unit4"
    "SALES",
        1312
        126
        1361
        6823
    "GOAL"
        1300
        160
        1200
        6000
    "EXTRA"
        "info1"
        "info2"
        "info3"
        "info4"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "improve"? Do you have any concrete doubts? Bad results from benchmarks?

Comment: I really can't make heads or tails of your representation of the table and the columns. Can you add an example of a simple table to your question, and how it looks in the maps?

Comment: I made a small Update @LukasEder. As I wrote, I have no reference to know if what I'm doing is acceptable just because it works or if this is the opposite of Java Pattern. =]